# How to get value of a FLAG in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

ClickHouse has flags for some options. For example, [allow_experimental_live_view](https://www.altinity.com/blog/2019/11/13/making-data-come-to-life-with-clickhouse-live-view-tables) can be set to 1 with:

```sql
:) SET allow_experimental_live_view = 1
```

But there is no `GET` to get the value of the flag, something like `GET allow_experimental_live_view`.

Is there any way to get the value of a flag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [system.settings](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/system_tables/#system-settings)-table to get the current status:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM system.settings
WHERE name = 'allow_experimental_live_view'
/*
┌─name─────────────────────────┬─value─┬─changed─┬─description──────────────────────────┬─min──┬─max──┬─readonly─┐
│ allow_experimental_live_view │ 0     │       1 │ Enable LIVE VIEW. Not mature enough. │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │        0 │
└──────────────────────────────┴───────┴─────────┴──────────────────────────────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────────┘
*/
```

With the new versions, there is also `getSetting` function for this.

```sql
SELECT getSetting('allow_experimental_live_view')

/*
┌─getSetting('allow_experimental_live_view')─┐
│                                          0 │
└────────────────────────────────────────────┘
*/
```